# Appcompat Alert Dialog Action button background On pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am trying new `AlertDialog` from appcompat v7 22.1.1.

It works pretty well (In all android versions) as in image.

[image]

Style for AlertDialog is this. (For now I am using hardcoded color values instead of color resources)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#111111</item>

            <item name="colorPrimary">#00ddff</item>

            <item name="colorAccent">#0044aa</item>

            <item name="colorButtonNormal">#00aaaa</item>

            <item name="colorControlHighlight">#00ddff</item>

            <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>

</style>
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
                <item name="colorAccent">#0044aa</item>
                <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
                <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
                <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle">
                <item name="android:textColor">#0044aa</item>
                <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title</item>
</style>
```

My question is ,

1) **how to change statePressed color which is rounded (Gray) in the image ?**

2) No pressed color is there in android >= 21 , what is hack for this ?

3) How can I have different colors of action buttons (Is it possible)?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use style attributes like

- `buttonBarButtonStyle`
- `buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle`
- `buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle`
- `buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle`

Example:

```xml
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/dialog_button.negative</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/dialog_button.positive</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog_button">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialogButtonSelector</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog_button.negative">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>

<style name="dialog_button.positive">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
</style>
```

Where `dialogButtonSelector` is our custom drawable selector.

Unfortunatelly setting background on `dialog_button` destroy our paddings and margins so I need to set it again.

`dialog_button` style can inherit through `Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog` but I found that it has missing styles like `textStyle` `bold`.

Comment: quite late on accepting the answer. Thnx for the great answer and working good.

Answer (score 2):

I have the Answer for the 3rd Questions
( How can I have different colors of action buttons (Is it possible)?  )

Code:

```
// Initialize AlertDialog & AlertDialog Builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("AlertDialog Title");
...........
......... 
//Build your AlertDialog 
AlertDialog Demo_alertDialog= builder.create();
Demo_alertDialog.show();

//For Positive Button:
Button b_pos; 
b_pos=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
if(b_pos!=null){
   b_pos.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }    


//For Neutral Button:
Button b_neu;
b_neu=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
if(b_neu!=null){
   b_neu.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }

//For Negative Button:
Button b_neg;
b_neg=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
if(b_neg!=null){
   b_neg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: that's a nice try. But I wanted it in theme. And the accepted answer works good. Though +1 for code version of it.

Comment: Thanks. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); builder.setMessage("Title"); builder.setCancelable(true);

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
alertdialog.show();

Button nbutton = alertdialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
nbutton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_press_white_rect));

Button pbutton = alertdialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
pbutton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_press_white_rect));

        **btn_press_white_rect.xml**

 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_rect_yellow" ></item>
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_rect_white" ></item>
</selector>
```